# HTML5 video wont play on IOs devices any browser, works on windows / android on all browsers

Tags: ios, safari, html5-video

I have backend (asp net core) sending video file  like so

```
public FileResult PlayVideo([FromRoute] string fileUrl)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "files/") + fileUrl;
            return PhysicalFile(path, contentType: "video/webm", enableRangeProcessing: true);
        }
```

in frontend I create blob from this route's response

```
fetch(source, options)
        .then((response) => response.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          console.log(blob)
          setUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        });
```

This blob is then used in video source

```
<video controls src={url} ref={videoPlayerRef} className="video-player" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()} />
```

Im using Browserstack to test and this works well on windows Chrome and Firefox (although Firefox gives warning to console failed to load URI but plays it anyway)

I't also works on Android phones, tested with Chrome and Firefox.

Problem is on IOs devices, video wont play on iPhone safari / chrome / firefox
also wont play on Mac safari / chrome / safari

What can I do to make it work on IOs devices ?

Comment: Is your `contentType: "video/webm"` including a VP9 video with a transparency? I don't think there's anything wrong with your code if it works okay elsewhere. This seems like a file format (**technical**) issue and not a **code** issue. Use MP4 for Apple devices. Use ProRes444 (inside MOV) if you need transparency...